# convert web-scraped data to json python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I have scraped a website, giving me 2 strings: one string is a name(i.e., texts in the code), the other is a collection of urls i have concatenated to one list. Now i would like to convert it into json

```
text=[]
text.append(texts+url)
alltexts=json.dumps(text)
return alltexts
```

I get a JSON like this

```
["AAA , 2858778011", "BBB , 2676882011", "CCC , 7589478011", "DDD , None", "EEE , None", "FFF , 1001423601"]
```

I would like to get it as something like this

```
{['name':'AAA','id':'2858778011'],['name':'BBB','id':'7589478011'],['name':'CCC','id':'None'],['name':'DDD','id':'None'],['name':'EEE','id':'1001423601']}
```

Comment: list are not dictionaries. u cannot use the form  ['name':'AAA','id':'2858778011'] instead u can use [{'name':'AAA','id':'2858778011'},....] and what is while appending how come u got comma in middle show some text and url data

Answer (score 1):

assume the texts , urls as below list . u  can generate the json as below

```
texts=["AAA", "BBB" "CCC","DDD","EEE","FFF"]
urls=["2858778011", "2676882011", "7589478011", "None", "None", "1001423601"]

text=[]
for i,j in zip(texts,urls):
    text.append({"name":i,"id":j})
```

or simply using list comprehension

```
text=[{"name":i,"id":j} for i,j in zip(texts,urls)]

alltexts=json.dumps(text)
```

using ur text

```
text=["AAA , 2858778011", "BBB , 2676882011", "CCC , 7589478011", "DDD , None", "EEE , None", "FFF , 1001423601"]

text=[{'name':i.split(',')[0].rstrip(),'id':i.split(',')[1].lstrip()} for i in text]

#output:[{'name': 'AAA', 'id': '2858778011'}, {'name': 'BBB', 'id': '2676882011'}, {'name': 'CCC', 'id': '7589478011'}, {'name': 'DDD', 'id': 'None'}, {'name': 'EEE', 'id': 'None'}, {'name': 'FFF', 'id': '1001423601'}]
```